# Strange Down-casted Array element failed to match the target type issue in Swift 3

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, core-data, swift3

When I'm trying to add my NSManagedObjects into the array I get this error:

```
Down-casted Array element failed to match the target type
```

I have this object: `<NSManagedObject: 0x60800009c390>` and want to put it into this array `[Item]` where

```
open class Item: NSManagedObject { ... }
```

and trying to do this via:

```
if let items = Item.withPredicate(predicate) {
    return items as! [Item]
}
```

and here I get this error. Why it happens on Swift 3 and does not on Swift 2?

How can I fix that?

Comment: Show more code...

Comment: @JérômeTeisseire what do you want to see? Which part?

Comment: It seems that you have an `NSManagedObject` not an `Item`. `Item` inherits from `NSManagedObject`, so you can put an `Item` into `[NSManagedObject]` but you can't put an `NSManagedObject` into `[Item]`

Comment: @Paulw11 so, how can I fix that? =/

Comment: Can you show the code for `allWithPredicate`?  It seems that it is returning a `[NSManagedObject]`

Comment: @Paulw11 yes, it returns `[NSManagedObject]?`

Comment: If the array truly contains `NSManagedObject` then you can't downcast to an array of `Item`; you could iterate the array and try to cast each object to an `Item`, but it seems likely that that will fail.  You need to look at `allWithPredicate` and have it return the appropriate type or just use `[NSManagedObject]`

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how you are using predicate like this.
To get the data of an entity with a predicate you use NSFetchRequest :

```
  let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
 let fetchrequest = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: "Item")
    let newentity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Item", in: context)
    fetchrequest.entity = newentity
    fetchrequest.predicate =  NSPredicate(format: "sirname == %@", "Jones")
    fetchrequest.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
    do {

        let results = try context.fetch(fetchrequest) as! [Item]

        for result in results {
            print("result sirname \n \(result.sirname)")
        }
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("error = \(error)")
    }
```

You are getting this error because you might have put wrong entityname in          NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Item", in: context)